# Xcode 6.2 Build Error

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

When I try to build a static library using Xcode 6.2, I get the following error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDateComponentsFormatter.h:36:5:
>   Unknown type name 'pthread_mutex_t'; did you mean 'pthread_attr_t'?

Clearly, NSDateComponentsFormatter.h is a file from Apple. I am not sure why we are getting this error and what to do about it. Can anyone give me a suggestion of what to do to get rid of this error?

This issue appears to be specifically related to Xcode 6.2. Can anyone offer any help with this issue? Thanks.